# How to validate EditText input in custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a custom view of an EditText with a TextView under it which says the error of the validation.

My idea is to make a validation of min and max length in my custom view and make visible or change text the TextView if the edittext input passes this validations or not, but I'm new at custom views and don't have any idea of how to reach it. I didn't find any EditText custom view like this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use material theme... https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

Answer (score 0):

#1 if you want only limit your edit text
get in your layout and set android:maxLength="5"

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/you_ed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="5"
      />
```

#2 if you want check edit text with onClicklistener

```
  button.setOnClickListener {
           if (binding.youEd.text.length>5){
               Toast.makeText(this, "error The input text is more than 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }else{
               //Execute the code if the input is correct
           }
        }
```

#3 If you want to check the input text momentarily (entry of each character from the user)

```
    you_ed.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
            if (text!!.length>5){
                Toast.makeText(this@IndexActivity, "error The input text is more than 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                //Execute the code if the input is correct
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: I know this is posible, but what I want is to use this behavior in a lot of activities, so I wanted to make a customview with edittext  and dont repeat the same behavior 10 times

Comment: you must make a function for it  in the object class 
I don't have any information about your views, if you would like to tell me so that I can guide you